# jQuery dialog opens with same selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-dialog

I have two orders A and B.
When I click on A, it opens up a dialog with a select option that defaults on blank but has Yes or No.
When I click on B ,it opens up a dialog with a select option as well; however, instead of defaulting on blank it carries over whatever I selected for A.

I need B to open up a fresh dialog the first time it is clicked.  I also need A to remember what the user selected last time.

I have tried `$("#input select option:selected").val("Y")`, and it does set the value; but does not on the UI itself.  This causes issues when I want to hide elements based on whether Y or N is selected.

Comment: Can you post a jsFiddle with what your currently have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to be saving the selected option somewhere, and setting the value of the `<select>` to that saved value when the dialog is opened.

Something like the below should get you started.

```
var orderData = {};  // -- An object to save the data into
var activeEl;        // -- Keep track of which button we've clicked

$('#btnOrder1,#btnOrder2').click(function(){

    // -- open the dialog
    $('#dialog').dialog({
        title:'Order Options',
        modal: true
    });

    // -- set the last clicked button to the ID of the one we clicked...
    activeEl = this.id;
    // -- set the select's option to the value we've stored. 
    // -- Unless we don't have a value, in which case we'll use "empty".
    $('#selOrderOption').val(orderData[activeEl] || '');
});

// -- set up the save click handler
$('#btnSave').click(function(){
    // -- save the selected value, keyed by the active button's ID
    orderData[activeEl] = $('#selOrderOption').val();
    $('#dialog').dialog("close");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/7Lds66td/

Comment: Thank you so much for doing this.  It actually helped me to realize that there's a difference between changing the value of the selector and the value of the selected option.